# Split a line by non-letter characters

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

Let say I have a minified javascript function like this:

```
function(){for(a=0;++a>0;){console.log(a);}}
```

and I want to apply an *agressive* split on it, that is insert a new line for some characters. So I would have

```
function(
)
{
for(
a=0;
++a>0;
)
{
console.log(
a
)
;
}
}
```

Of course I can use multiple substitute like :

```
:s/{/{\r/g
:s/}/\r}/g
:s/(/(\r/g
:s/)/\r)/g
...
```

But.

Is there a way to use one (or two) substitute(s) to do the whole job?

Comment: Didn't try non-alphabet? \W

Comment: You can specify what particular characters you wanted to put. It seemd that your statements contains =,.,+ as well

Answer (score 4):

yes, like this:

```
%s/[}{();]/&\r/g
```

Just noticed that, the output of above leave a:

```
a)
```

If it does matter, you can do a:

```
%s/.\zs)/\r)/g
```

to fix it.